# Set Enviroment Variable for Desktop Environment, Bash and ZSH is a single place

Tags: environment-variables

Currently to set environment variable for Gnome, Bash and ZSH; I have to maintain two files (`.profile` and `.zshenv`).

Is there any way I can set the variables from one source.